# Flatness of a Restriction Map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I have some questions (red tagged in image below) about a equation in the proof of Prop. 7.1.12 in Liu's "Algebraic Geometry" (page 256):

[image]

1) Why is the morphism $O_X(U) \to O_X(V)$ flat? By assumption $U$ is affine, so if $V = D(f)$ then $O_X(V) = O_X(U)_f$ will be as a localisation certainly flat, but why it holds for a general $V \subset U$?

2) Why $I = Ann(b)$ annihilates $O_{X,x}$?

Comment: Question 1): That's because flatness is a local property.

Comment: Q2. Note that $I\mathcal{O}_{x,X} \subset \mathcal{O}_{x,X}$. Now mulitplication by $b$ on $\mathcal{O}_{x,X}$ is injective by definition, but multiplication on $I\mathcal{O}_{x,X}$ is zero by definition of $I$. Thus $I\mathcal{O}_{x,X} = 0$.